# Form Details section loading blank after change in VBA

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I recently made some changes in the VBA of a form, and now the Details section of the Form in Form view loads blank. I can see the header, and the number of records is listed at the bottom, but the Details section now loads blank. My assumption then is that the VBA code cause this to happen, as I changed no form settings.

I had done some trouble shooting in adding some new functions to an area of the form. Everything went fine. I then duplicated the code I used and modified it to do the same thing for a different part of the form. For context, this form is just a Review Page, it pulls data from several tables into a summary page. This hasn't been an issue before, and I confirmed with my back up that all the setting are the same, and the back-up does not have this issue. The only difference in the backup and this current form is added controls and command buttons, and some VBA. Yet the back-up loads correctly, and my new file does not. I have copied the VBA below in case something sticks out to you all that may because the issue. I did add to the VBA in the Form Load and Current sections, but it was just a duplication of code that was already there. I copied the code referencing Software and SW to say Hardware and HW. I'm not sure why that may be causing an issue. All code referencing Software was tested and worked satisfactorily, so I duplicated it all for Hardware. Somewhere in that lies the problem. I have copied all of the VBA for the entire form. Sorry for the length, but I thought it could be informative. You may notice sloppy work or inefficient use of code, as I am still new to this, but hopefully it makes sense. If I can clarify anything or explain what I was trying to accomplish with a particular function, please don't hesitate.

I greatly appreciate any assistance.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub cmdAddSWRev_Click()

Me.lstSWRevAdd.Visible = True
Me.lstSWRevDateAdd.Visible = True
Me.lstSWRevNotesAdd.Visible = True
Me.lblSwRevAdd.Visible = True
Me.lblSWRevDateAdd.Visible = True
Me.lblSWRevNotesAdd.Visible = True

Me.lstSWRev.Visible = False
Me.lstSWRevDate.Visible = False
Me.lstSWRevNotes.Visible = False
Me.lblSWRev.Visible = False
Me.lblSWRevDate.Visible = False
Me.lblSWRevNotes.Visible = False

Me.cmdSaveSWRev.Visible = True

End Sub


Private Sub cmdHWRevAdd_Click()

Me.lstHWRevAdd.Visible = True
Me.lstHWRevDateAdd.Visible = True
Me.lstHWRevNotesAdd.Visible = True
Me.lblHWRevAdd.Visible = True
Me.lblHWRevDateAdd.Visible = True
Me.lblHWRevNotesAdd.Visible = True

Me.lstHWRev.Visible = False
Me.lstHWRevDate.Visible = False
Me.lstHWRevNotes.Visible = False
Me.lblHWRev.Visible = False
Me.lblHWRevDate.Visible = False
Me.lblHWRevNotes.Visible = False

Me.cmdSaveHWRev.Visible = True

End Sub

Private Sub cmdSaveSWRev_Click()

'Create an entry in Software Revisions

   Dim SerialNumberDatabase As DAO.Database
   Dim tblSoftwareRevisions As DAO.Recordset


   Set SerialNumberDatabase = CurrentDb
   Set tblSoftwareRevisions = SerialNumberDatabase.OpenRecordset("tblSoftwareRevisions")

   tblSoftwareRevisions.AddNew
   tblSoftwareRevisions("SoftwareRevision").Value = Me.lstSWRevAdd
   tblSoftwareRevisions("Assembly").Value = Me.PartNumber_tblUnits
   tblSoftwareRevisions("SWRevDate").Value = Me.lstSWRevDateAdd
   tblSoftwareRevisions("Notes").Value = Me.lstSWRevNotesAdd
   tblSoftwareRevisions.Update
   tblSoftwareRevisions.Close

'Add the new Software Revision ID to the existing unit in tblUnits by editing the Null SoftwareID field

 Dim tblUnits As DAO.Recordset
 Set tblUnits = SerialNumberDatabase.OpenRecordset("tblUnits")

 tblUnits.MoveFirst
   Do Until tblUnits.EOF
      If tblUnits!SerialNumber = Me.lstSerialNumber And tblUnits!PartNumber = Me.lstPartNumber Then
         tblUnits.Edit
         tblUnits!SoftwareID = DMax("SWRevID", "tblSoftwareRevisions")
         tblUnits.Update
      End If
      tblUnits.MoveNext
   Loop

   MsgBox ("The Software Revision has been added for this unit")


End Sub
Private Sub cmdSaveHWRev_Click()

'Create an entry in Software Revisions

   Dim SerialNumberDatabase As DAO.Database
   Dim tblHardwareRevisions As DAO.Recordset


   Set SerialNumberDatabase = CurrentDb
   Set tblHardwareRevisions =     SerialNumberDatabase.OpenRecordset("tblHardwareRevisions")

   tblHardwareRevisions.AddNew
   tblHardwareRevisions("HardwareRevision").Value = Me.lstHWRevAdd
   tblHardwareRevisions("Assembly").Value = Me.PartNumber_tblUnits
   tblHardwareRevisions("HWRevDate").Value = Me.lstHWRevDateAdd
   tblHardwareRevisions("Notes").Value = Me.lstHWRevNotesAdd
   tblHardwareRevisions.Update
   tblHardwareRevisions.Close

'Add the new Software Revision ID to the existing unit in tblUnits by editing the Null SoftwareID field

 Dim tblUnits As DAO.Recordset
 Set tblUnits = SerialNumberDatabase.OpenRecordset("tblUnits")

 tblUnits.MoveFirst
   Do Until tblUnits.EOF
      If tblUnits!SerialNumber = Me.lstSerialNumber And tblUnits!PartNumber = Me.lstPartNumber Then
         tblUnits.Edit
         tblUnits!HardwareID = DMax("HWRevID", "tblHardwareRevisions")
         tblUnits.Update
      End If
      tblUnits.MoveNext
   Loop
        tblUnits.Close
   MsgBox ("The Hardware Revision has been added for this unit")


End Sub
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()

DoCmd.ShowAllRecords
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdFind


End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()

Me.lstUnitBuiltDate.Requery

If Me.txtSerialCount.Value > 1 Then
Me.tblReportedIssues_subform_Label.Visible = True
Me.tblReportedIssues_subform.Visible = True
Else
Me.tblReportedIssues_subform_Label.Visible = False
Me.tblReportedIssues_subform.Visible = False
End If

If Me.txtRMACount.Value > 1 Then
Me.tblReportedIssues_subform1_Label.Visible = True
Me.tblReportedIssues_subform1.Visible = True
Else
Me.tblReportedIssues_subform1_Label.Visible = False
Me.tblReportedIssues_subform1.Visible = False
End If

If Me.lstSerialNumber.Value < 1 Then
Me.txtSerialNote.Visible = True
Else
Me.txtSerialNote.Visible = False
End If

Me.lstSWRevAdd.Visible = False
Me.lstSWRevDateAdd.Visible = False
Me.lstSWRevNotesAdd.Visible = False
Me.lblSwRevAdd.Visible = False
Me.lblSWRevDateAdd.Visible = False
Me.lblSWRevNotesAdd.Visible = False
Me.cmdSaveSWRev.Visible = False

Me.lstSWRev.Visible = True
Me.lstSWRevDate.Visible = True
Me.lstSWRevNotes.Visible = True
Me.lblSWRev.Visible = True
Me.lblSWRevDate.Visible = True
Me.lblSWRevNotes.Visible = True

Me.lstHWRevAdd.Visible = False
Me.lstHWRevDateAdd.Visible = False
Me.lstHWRevNotesAdd.Visible = False
Me.lblHWRevAdd.Visible = False
Me.lblHWRevDateAdd.Visible = False
Me.lblHWRevNotesAdd.Visible = False
Me.cmdSaveHWRev.Visible = False

Me.lstHWRev.Visible = True
Me.lstHWRevDate.Visible = True
Me.lstHWRevNotes.Visible = True
Me.lblHWRev.Visible = True
Me.lblHWRevDate.Visible = True
Me.lblHWRevNotes.Visible = True

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()

Me.lstSWRevAdd.Visible = False
Me.lstSWRevDateAdd.Visible = False
Me.lstSWRevNotesAdd.Visible = False
Me.lblSwRevAdd.Visible = False
Me.lblSWRevDateAdd.Visible = False
Me.lblSWRevNotesAdd.Visible = False
Me.cmdSaveSWRev.Visible = False

Me.lstSWRev.Visible = True
Me.lstSWRevDate.Visible = True
Me.lstSWRevNotes.Visible = True
Me.lblSWRev.Visible = True
Me.lblSWRevDate.Visible = True
Me.lblSWRevNotes.Visible = True

Me.lstHWRevAdd.Visible = False
Me.lstHWRevDateAdd.Visible = False
Me.lstHWRevNotesAdd.Visible = False
Me.lblHWRevAdd.Visible = False
Me.lblHWRevDateAdd.Visible = False
Me.lblHWRevNotesAdd.Visible = False
Me.cmdSaveHWRev.Visible = False

Me.lstHWRev.Visible = True
Me.lstHWRevDate.Visible = True
Me.lstHWRevNotes.Visible = True
Me.lblHWRev.Visible = True
Me.lblHWRevDate.Visible = True
Me.lblHWRevNotes.Visible = True

Me.lstUnitBuiltDate.Requery

End Sub

Private Sub lstRMA_Click()

MsgBox "This cannot be Edited or Altered", vbCritical, "Field Locked"

End Sub

Private Sub tblReportedIssues_subform_Enter()

MsgBox "This cannot be Edited or Altered. If you would like to review a listed RMA, please use the Search or Navigation buttons to locate it.", vbCritical, "Field Locked"

End Sub
```

If it matters, the form has a record source of "SELECT tblReportedIssues.*, tblUnits.Notes, tblUnits.SerialNumber AS SerialNumber_tblUnits, tblUnits.PartNumber AS PartNumber_tblUnits FROM tblUnits INNER JOIN (tblRMA INNER JOIN tblReportedIssues ON tblRMA.RMANumber = tblReportedIssues.RMA) ON (tblUnits.PartNumber = tblReportedIssues.PartNumber) AND (tblUnits.SerialNumber = tblReportedIssues.SerialNumber); "

With Settings as follows:
Record Set: Dynaset
Fetch Defaults: Yes
Filter: (blank)
Filter On Load: No
Order By: (blank)
Order on Load: No
Wait for Post Processing: No
Data Entry: No
Allow Additions: No
Allow Deletions: No
Allow Edits: Yes
Allow Filters: Yes
Record Locks: No Locks

These settings and Record Source work on my back-up file in that they allow everything to load correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot. After much investigation, it appears I accidentally selected the Detail bar in design mode and changed its visibility to No while I was trying to hide other controls.